# CSS transition not working in Safari (using flexbox and transform)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, flexbox

I made a css transition for navigation items in my web pages main nav.

It's a relativley simple effect using the items before element to mask out and hide the text using css transforms and flexbox.

I developed in Chrome and tested in Firefox and Safari (all latest versions) and had to discover that Safari ist not displaying the transition correctly.

I created a short pen, so you can get an idea of the effect.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/owntbier

Is there any way to fix it?
I guess it has something to do with the way that safari interprets the "justify-content" property.

Here is the Code:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>WHY SAFARI, WHY?</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.container{
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)   translateY(-50%);
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  color: #ff9900;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: 900;

  &:hover{

    &:before{
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }

  &:before{
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    color: #131313;
    content: 'WHY SAFARI, WHY?';
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 0%;
    transition: max-width 0.5s ease;
  }
}
```

**NOTE**
Necessary vendor prefixes are automatically added by my preprocessor

Comment: You try safari on windows?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @RaimondasKazlauskas Safari on Windows !?

Comment: @SlimMarten sorry for question, but i try to understand the problem. If problem is on flexbox, can you try to add prefixes?

     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -webkit-flex;

and for transforms:

     -webkit-transform

Comment: @RaimondasKazlauskas in my production style sheet are all necessary vendor prefixes added. For the sake of simplicity I didn't add them in the question above

Answer (score 0):

Your code wont work on Internet explorer 9 also .
all you need to add is ::

For Safari--

```
**-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%)   translateY(-50%);**
```

For IE9--

```
**-ms-transform:translateX(-50%)   translateY(-50%);**
```

Hope it works.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments above, all vendor prefixes are added to the compiled stylesheet. I didn't add them here for the sake of simplicity. And no,...it doesn't fix the problem